# Symmetries of multifocal ellipses

Tags: permutations, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, symmetry

A classical ellipse has two foci (I hope my English is correct saying this) and admits the Klein group as isometry group, whose elements are the identity, the reflexions along the small and larges axes, and the central symmetry whose fixed point is the middle of the segment the two foci define. Those symmetries preserve the set of foci globally, that is, they induce a permutation thereof.

I would like to know if similarly, given a set of $N+1$ points $F_{i}$ for $i\in[0,N]\cap\mathbb{Z}$ of the $N$-dimensional euclidean space, the isometry group of the locus of the points $M$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{N}MF_{i}=K>0$ induces a permutation of the points $F_{i}$.

Can we even go farther and consider and uncountable set of points and prove that $C_{\rho}(K):=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\int_{0}^{1}\vert z-\rho e^{2i\pi t}\vert dt=K>0\}$ is a circle for all $\rho\geq 0$?

Comment: In the case of dimension N=3, if the foci are situated on a  **non regular** tetrahedron ( $N+1=4$ vertices) , I doubt that you will get any symmetry in the generalized ellipsoid you will get.

Comment: So do I, but the identity trivially permutes those vertices. Of course the interesting cases require a minimal amount of symmetry of the considered "hyperellipsoid".

Comment: I am more or less convinced that the group of permutations leaving invariant the generalized ellipsoid associated with foci $F_k, k=1... (N+1)$ is the same as the group of permutations leaving invariant the set of points $F_k$, and that this group is in general reduced to $\{Id\}$ for a random placement of points $F_k$.

Comment: That can't be true, as the Klein group is of order $4$, while the group of permutations of two elements (here the two foci) is of order $2$. A loss of injectivity occurs while going from the isometry group to the permutation group of the foci.

Comment: With the ellipse, you are not in the case you are interested in ! The dimension of the ambient space is $N=2$ and you have $N=2$ foci, not $N+1=3$ !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample showing (thanks to Desmos) that in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $N=2$, a super-ellipse defined by $N+1=3$ foci isn't preserved by any symmetry because the foci are in the same situation (sorry, points are in $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$...)

But, have I well understood your question ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, the absence of non trivial symmetry whatsoever doesn't constitute by itself a counterexample. But your picture inspires me another question that I may ask separately if needed: are the points of the curve of local maximal curvature reached by the lines joining the center of gravity to the foci?

Comment: Your (new) question needs to be asked separately ; but, prior to that, do you have attempted numerical computations showing that this property is plausible ?

Comment: No, I'm terrible at performing numerical computations.